# How to update angular-plotly.js plot when data changes in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, flask, plot, plotly.js

I am developing app in Angular 8 and displaying 'scatter' plot using angular-plotly.js. For data in x,y I am getting data from rest api. And I am able to plot graph using the data from rest api. On frontend I have a two dropdown from where user can select option and send those options value to backend and in response I get new data back to frontend. Till this point everything works fine, but the issue I am facing is that my plot is not getting updated with new data. Frontend still showing the initial plot not the new plot with different data value.

**My Html code:**

Here is my two dropdown from where user select options and based on this options from backend through restapi I receive data points to plot my graph. And when user changes any option from dropdown and submit new choice to backend I again receive new data point and I need to remove my old plot and display new plot based on new dataset.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="segmentSelection()" #ff="ngForm">
            <div id="userSelection" ngModelGroup="userData" #userData="ngModelGroup">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Choose Segment Key</mat-label>
            <mat-select id="selectme" ngModel name="segmentKey">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let segment of segKeys" [value]="segment">
                {{segment}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field style="margin-left: 30px;">
            <mat-label>Choose Target Variable</mat-label>
            <mat-select id="myselect" ngModel name="target_variable">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let msg of mymessage" [value]="msg">
                {{msg}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-color" (click)="plotDiv()" style="margin-left: 20px;">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>

<plotly-plot [data]="graph.data" [layout]="graph.layout"></plotly-plot>
```

**My component.ts code:**

```
myhistoricPlot = []
myhistoricDate = []

segmentSelection(){
  this.plotselection.segmentKey = this.segmentData.value.userData.segmentKey;
  this.plotselection.target_variable = this.segmentData.value.userData.target_variable;
  console.log(this.segmentData);
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/data-decomposition", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },body: JSON.stringify({
      segmentKey: this.segmentData.value.userData.segmentKey,
      target_variable: this.segmentData.value.userData.target_variable
    })
  }).then(res => res.json()
    // console.log(res);
    // console.log('hello saheb')
    // console.log(res.json())

  ).then(myjson => {

    myjson['Data'].forEach(element =>{
      this.myhistoricPlot.push(element)
    })
    myjson['Date'].forEach(element =>{
      this.myhistoricDate.push(element)
    })
    // console.log(this.myhistoricPlot)})
    // this.myhistoricDate = myjson['Date'];
    // this.myhistoricPlot = myjson['Data'];
    console.log(this.myhistoricDate);
    console.log(this.myhistoricPlot);
    console.log(myjson)
    this.myhistoricPlot = [];
    this.myhistoricDate = [];
    })
}

public graph = {
    data: [
        { x: this.myhistoricDate, y: this.myhistoricPlot, type: 'scatter', mode: 'lines+points', marker: {color: 'black'} },

    ],
    layout: {width: 1200, height: 600, title: 'Historical Actuals Plot'}
};
```

****Note: myhistoricDate, myhistoricPlot are the two list with some numerical values, in which I am receiving data from restapi.

Thank you....your help on this issue would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Object and arrays are bound by reference, so Angular won't detect a change to  `graph.data` until its reference is changed. I usually use a helper method to ensure that happens.

```js
segmentSelection() {
  ...
  .then(myjson => this.setData(myjson.Date, myjson.Data));
}

setData(x, y) {
  this.data[0].x = x;
  this.data[1].y = y;
  this.data = { ...this.data };
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing that angular won't detect change unless the reference is changed.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Trevor Karjanis it does not work because typescript is call by reference. So as long as you don't reasign your graph to a new object Angular won't detect the change as the reference is still the same in your code. However you could also just reasign the graph object like so:

```
    .then(myjson => {

    myjson['Data'].forEach(element =>{
      this.myhistoricPlot.push(element)
    })
    myjson['Date'].forEach(element =>{
      this.myhistoricDate.push(element)
    })
    // console.log(this.myhistoricPlot)})
    this.myhistoricDate = myjson['Date'];
    this.myhistoricPlot = myjson['Data'];
    this.graph = {
    data: [
        { x: this.myhistoricDate, y: this.myhistoricPlot, type: 'scatter', mode: 'lines+points', marker: {color: 'black'} },

    ],
    layout: {width: 1200, height: 600, title: 'Historical Actuals Plot'}
}; 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `ChangeDetectionStrategy`:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['...'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export MyComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private _cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

...
).then(myjson => {

    myjson['Data'].forEach(element =>{
      this.myhistoricPlot.push(element)
    })
    myjson['Date'].forEach(element =>{
      this.myhistoricDate.push(element)
    })
    // console.log(this.myhistoricPlot)})
    // this.myhistoricDate = myjson['Date'];
    // this.myhistoricPlot = myjson['Data'];
    console.log(this.myhistoricDate);
    console.log(this.myhistoricPlot);
    console.log(myjson)

    this._cd.detectChanges();
    ...
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.myhistoricDate.splice(0)` and `this.myhistoricPlot.splice(0)` instead of `this.myhistoricDate` & `this.myhistoricPlot`. This will create a new array and angular will recognize it as a change which will lead to updating the plot.